# syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

Tags: c++

I have written a simple class with two property(arrays).
I am trying to initiliaize all the array element to 0 or NULL but the compiler(vc++ 2010) throw me errors.

```
class Marina{
public:
char port[100];
char bport[25];

Marina(){
this->port = {0};
this->bport = {0}; 
}

};
```

I have also tried a simple statement like this:

```
class Marina(){
public:
char port[100] = {0};
char port[25] = {0};



};
```

Comment: Close your constructor definition, add a } before };

Answer (score 4):

You need this:

```
Marina() : port(), bport() {}
```

This initializes both arrays with full of zeroes.

In C++11 you can define non-static member variables at the point of declaration, so you could do this:

```
class Marina {
public:
  char port[100] = {0};
  char bport[25] = {0};
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Marina(){
//std::fill is in <algorithm>
std::fill (port, port + 100, 0);
std::fill (bport, bport + 25, 0);
```

This code segment is missing something. There's no ending brace! I replaced your assignments with something that will work as long as the brace is there.

Beside that, your code will still not compile that way as initialization has to be done in the initializer list:

```
Marina()
    : port ({0}), bport ({0}) {}
```

Comment: I just realized that. Either use member initializers, or don't try to assign something to an array after it's already been created. Instead, use `std::fill`.

Comment: I think you need `bport{0}` rather than `bport({0})`

Comment: @juanchopanza, I actually thought you needed parentheses. Apparently not :) GCC doesn't complain at all about `()`, `{0}` or `({0})` though, so I guess that comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Ah OK, it doesn't compile for me. Can you try compiling with `-pedantic-errors`? You need either empty `()` or `{}`, or `{}` if you want to put values in.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I always have the highest warning/error level. Checked it again to make sure. That's odd, but I guess I won't use `({})` anymore if it doesn't compile on whatever you're using. Could be a bug in GCC 4.6.2 or something too.

Comment: I am on gcc4.7 but I can check 4.6. What compiler options are you using?

Comment: @juanchopanza -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Weffc++

Comment: OK, I was wrong. It compiles with warnings, on gcc 4.7: warning: list-initializer for non-class type must not be parenthesized

Answer (score 0):

Your braces don't match. You have one more open brace than close braces. Code with mismatched braces is ill-formed. Unfortunately, compiler messages in response to a missing close brace are not always the clearest. How is the compiler to know which open brace you forgot to close with a close brace?

Comment: I didnt forgot to close the braces.

Comment: @user1341970: The code you showed does not have matching open and close braces. Count them.