# Array Initialization confusion

Tags: c++

I have gone through [question 1] ([Initialization of a normal array with one default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/c-c-initialization-of-a-normal-array-with-one-default-value)) and [question 2] ([How to initialize an array in C++ objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694689/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c-objects)) But I could not understand below behaviour.

```
int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    arr[5] = {-1}; // option 1
    int arr1[5] = { -1 }; //option 2
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << arr1[i] << " ";
}
```

Option 1 gives : GARBAGE VALUES
Option 2 gives values : AS EXPECTED
Please explain in simple terms why I don't see the same behaviour in both option 1 and option2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In option 1, you are have an uninitialzed array

```
int arr[5];
```

Then you assign a value out of bounds

```
arr[5] = {-1};
```

since the only valid indicies are `[0]` to `[4]`.

Comment: I did that by mistake which you must have understood why because I was thinking totally wrong. But your answer made me understand that I am assigning values to indices not initializing like in option 2. Thanks!